# Не компилируется в apk

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

В чем проблема? Баг SDK того времени я пофиксил, Unity 5.6.4p2. (до этого на самой новой версии все компилировал спокойно на Андроид)
На Windows все скомпилировалось, а на Андроид - нет.

Полный список ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
E:/Downloads/jdk\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/Eloren/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Знаю, вам непонятно так же, как и мне, но может, кто сталкивался.

Comment: Вы используете нестандартный класс `sun,misc.BASE64Encoder`. И этот класс не удаётся найти при сборке apk.

Comment: Что делать? Что это за класс и где он?

Comment: Вы явно используете этот класс в своём коде?

Comment: Если вы явно его используете, то используйте вместо него стандартный класс `java.util.Base64`

Comment: Я просто не понимаю даже о чем речь

Comment: И еще "Error building Players: 2 errors" без объяснения в коносоли, вторая ошибка из двух. Больше их нет

Comment: Какую версию Java Development Kit (JDK) вы прописали для использования в Unity3D? Вот тут про это есть: https://boostlog.io/@mohammedalsayedomar/setup-android-sdk-and-jdk-in-unity-5adad03d47018500491f3f77

Comment: СПАСИБО! Закиньте в ответы, помечу как ответ

Comment: Что именно помогло? Что поместить в качестве ответа?

Comment: ссылка на boostlog

Comment: Я добавил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего в настройках вашего проекта не прописан путь к JDK (Java Development Kit) и при сборке Unity просто не может найти нужных классов. В данном случае `sun.misc.Base64`.

Проверьте настройки Android SDK и JDK в вашем проекте и [пропишите нужные пути](https://boostlog.io/@mohammedalsayedomar/setup-android-sdk-and-jdk-in-unity-5adad03d47018500491f3f77), если это требуется.